# Taxonomy Category category.php not working

Tags: posts, categories, customization, taxonomy, post-type

I have created custom post type, taxonomy and categorys. When viewing the category it seems to be using index.php and ignoring the WordPress template hierarchy.

Any ideas why category.php, category-{id}.php etc aren't working for the custom post type categorys but working fine for regular posts?

thanks

```
add_action('init', 'collegestampede_register');

function collegestampede_register() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'College Stampede', 'post type general name',
        'singular_name' => 'Member', 'post type singular name',
        'add_new' => 'Add New', 'stampede item',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Member',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Member',
        'new_item' => 'New Member',
        'view_item' => 'View Member',
        'search_items' => 'Search Member',
        'not_found' => 'Nothing found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'Nothing found in Trash',
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/article16.png',
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','excerpt',)

      ); 

    register_post_type( 'stampedemember' , $args );

register_taxonomy("Location", array("stampedemember"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Location", "singular_label" => "Location", "rewrite" => true));
```

Comment: Please post relevant code, including primarily the `register_taxonomy()` call, and, if necessary, the `register_post_type()` call.

Comment: @Storm3y `category.php` and `category-{id}.php` work only for standard categories. For the taxonomy `Location` you should use `taxonomy-location.php` or `taxonomy-location-{slug}.php`

Comment: @G.M.taxonomy-location.php doesn't appear to be working either.

Answer (score 1):

For a custom taxonomy named `Location` (p.s. you may have issues with a capitalized slug), [per the Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display), the taxonomy archive index template file is `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php`, or `taxonomy-Location.php` (note capitalization).

Comment: taxonomy-location.php or taxonomy-Location.php doesn't appear to be working

Comment: Why? Can you post a live link to a page that should be using that template?